# How to find out if USB flash drives are USB 2.0 or 3.0

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I inherited a lot of USB flash drives and would like to find out what USB version they are (i.e. 2.0, 3.0 or maybe even older). How can I do that on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Check the color of the insulator strip in the connector.

A 2.0 device will have a black or white insulator.  A 3.0 device will have a blue insulator and a 3.2 device is supposed to have a red insulator, but I've never seen a devices rated for 3.2 in the wild.

Comment: Is there no way to check this with software?